# Using column from another table in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to use a column from another table when i use trigger `before insert` but i get an error `Unknown table in field list`

Here is an example code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER electricity_consumption_B_update
before insert ON electr
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
set new.electricity_consumption =  (new.`Printer_power_VT` * new.`electricity_kVT/hr` * slicer.printing_time_hr * 0.001);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

the column from another table is "printing_time_hr" from table "slicer"

Please help, what to do, how to use the column from another table

Comment: I think you should change the update to  `set new.electricity_consumption = new.Printer_power_VT  *  new.electricity_kVT/hr  * 0.001 * ( select slicer.printing_time_hr from slicer condition ... ) `

Comment: The error is clear  column `printing_time_hr` isn't declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER electricity_consumption_B_update
before insert ON electr
DECLARE _printing_time_hr    INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT printing_time_hr INTO _printing_time_hr
  FROM slicer
 where ... ;
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
set new.electricity_consumption =  (new.`Printer_power_VT` * new.`electricity_kVT/hr` * _printing_time_hr * 0.001);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```